# Port of php str_word_count to c#

Tags: c#, php

I'm migrating a legacy PHP application to .net, and one of the requirements is that the URLs stay exactly as before.

To generate friendly URLs the legacy application uses [`str_word_count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php),  I was wondering if there is a port of this function to C#?

Comment: AFAIK there's no built-in function to do this with C#. You can probably write something fairly easily, though.

Comment: [Check out my google search results](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=c%23+word+count+function&oq=c%23+word+count+function&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.2799.15398.0.15584.45.25.11.5.5.2.320.4450.0j16j7j1.24.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.jTOzzkTEyAA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=f0056a833a456726&ion=1&biw=1280&bih=939)

Comment: Do you have to support various locales (i.e special characters such as é), or is the western alphabet enough (I should hope so if this is related to URLs). I'll post my answer anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay here's my "bad C#" example (mimicking PHP in the mixed return type). It's a fairly trivial implementation leveraging .NET's Regular Expressions.

```
private enum WORD_FORMAT
{
    NUMBER = 0,
    ARRAY = 1,
    ASSOC = 2
};

private static object str_word_count(string str, WORD_FORMAT format, string charlist)
{
    string wordchars = string.Format("{0}{1}", "a-z", Regex.Escape(charlist));

    var words = Regex.Matches(str, string.Format("[{0}]+(?:[{0}'\\-]+[{0}])?", wordchars), RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    if (format == WORD_FORMAT.ASSOC)
    {
        var assoc = new Dictionary<int, string>(words.Count);
        foreach (Match m in words)
            assoc.Add(m.Index, m.Value);
        return assoc;
    }
    else if (format == WORD_FORMAT.ARRAY)
    {
        return words.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();
    }
    else // default to number.
    {
        return words.Count;
    }
}
```

So the function will return a `Dictionary<int,string>` if you choose `ASSOC`, a `string[]` if you choose `ARRAY` and a simple `int` if you choose `NUMBER`.

An example (I copied PHP's example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sentence = @"Hello fri3nd, you're
   looking          good today!";

    var assoc = (Dictionary<int,string>)str_word_count(sentence, WORD_FORMAT.ASSOC, string.Empty);
    var array = (string[])str_word_count(sentence, WORD_FORMAT.ARRAY, string.Empty);
    var number = (int)str_word_count(sentence, WORD_FORMAT.NUMBER, string.Empty);

    //test the plain array
    Console.WriteLine("Array\n(");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("\t[{0}] => {1}", i, array[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(")");
    // test the associative
    Console.WriteLine("Array\n(");
    foreach (var kvp in assoc)
        Console.WriteLine("\t[{0}] => {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(")");
    //test the charlist:
    array = (string[])str_word_count(sentence, WORD_FORMAT.ARRAY, "àáãç3");
    Console.WriteLine("Array\n(");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("\t[{0}] => {1}", i, array[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(")");
    //test the number
    Console.WriteLine("\n{0}", number);
    Console.Read();
}
```

But, I'd like to add a note here: Don't return objects. It works aok with PHP because it's not a strongly typed language. Really, you should be writing individual versions of the function to cater for each different format. Anyways, that should get you started :)

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => fri
    [2] => nd
    [3] => you're
    [4] => looking
    [5] => good
    [6] => today
)
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [6] => fri
    [10] => nd
    [14] => you're
    [25] => looking
    [42] => good
    [47] => today
)
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => fri3nd
    [2] => you're
    [3] => looking
    [4] => good
    [5] => today
)

7
```

Comment: Instead of using a dictionary, why can't you use an array? Does it not always increment by 1?

Comment: Dictionary for associativity. It's mapping word indices to the word itself, you could also use a HashMap or something similar, but not an array. I do return an array when the requested format is an array though.